ASP.NET MVC & C# : cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> to System.Linq.IQueryable<T>
I have a list of application which I first filter by those who have paid:
var boapApplicants = _BOAPRepository.GetBOAPApplicantsList_Paid();

It then takes that list and puts it into a new selection of checkbox items so that the user can check off those who need further action:
IList<SelectionCheckBoxItem> selectionCheckBoxItems = new List<SelectionCheckBoxItem>();

selectionCheckBoxItems = GetSelectionCheckBoxItemsList(boapApplicants, selectionCheckBoxItems.ToList());

The top lines of GetSelectionCheckBoxItemsList look like this:
private List<SelectionCheckBoxItem> GetSelectionCheckBoxItemsList(IList<BOAPApplicant> boapApplicants, List<SelectionCheckBoxItem> selectioncheckBoxItems)
{
    foreach (var applicant in boapApplicants)
    {
        selectioncheckBoxItems.Add(

This returns than placed in a virtual model which has CheckBoxItemsPagedList defined as:
public IPagedList<SelectionCheckBoxItem> CheckBoxItemsPagedList { get; set; }

The final part is to take the list and checkboxitems and place them in the virtual models PagedList:
var pageNumber = page == null || page <= 0 ? 1 : page.Value;
var pageSize = 20;

vm.CheckBoxItemsPagedList = new PagedList<BOAPApplicant>(selectionCheckBoxItems, pageNumber, pageSize);

However, I'm getting the error

Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<DataDesigns.Models.SelectionCheckBoxItem>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DataDesigns.Data.BOAPApplicant>'

on this last line of code.
The PagedList and SelectionCheckBoxItem work in other area of the website but not when I've tried to combine the two. I've tried various combinations of List, Queryable, Enumerable, but nothing seems to work.

From the look of the error, it's a mismacth issue when you are trying to create a PagedList from selectionCheckBoxItems list. The error occurs because you're passing a list of SelectionCheckBoxItem objects where the constructor expects an IQueryable.
Can you update your last line to this
vm.CheckBoxItemsPagedList = new PagedList(selectionCheckBoxItems, pageNumber, pageSize);

According to your sharing, the PagedList should be somewhat new PagedList<T>(IQueryable<T>, pageNumber, pageSize);, and since you define the T to be BOAPApplicant, so that the variable selectionCheckBoxItems should be IQueryable<BOAPApplicant>, but it's obvious that selectionCheckBoxItems is new List<SelectionCheckBoxItem>(), so that you need to change to new PagedList<SelectionCheckBoxItem> or new PagedList<BOAPApplicant>(BOAPApplicantList.

The the rest is to convert list to IQueryable, maybe you need something similar to var list = new List<string>(); var queryable = list.AsQueryable();
